# FakeItEasy not finding call although its there

Tags: c#, .net, unit-testing, fakeiteasy

I experience some strange problems with FakeItEasy.

Imagine following unit test method:

```
[TestMethod]
public void DeletePerson_WhenCalled_ThenPersonIsDeleted()
{
    const int personId = 24;
    var commonParam = new CommonParam();

    this.testee.DeletePerson(commonParam, personId );

    A.CallTo(() => this.personRepository.DeletePersons(commonParam, new[] {personId }, false)).MustHaveHappened(Repeated.Exactly.Once);
    A.CallTo(() => this.personRepository.SaveChanges()).MustHaveHappened(Repeated.Exactly.Once);
}
```

The `testee.DeletePerson`-method looks like this:

```
public ResultatModel DeletePerson(CommonParam commonParam, int personId )
{
    this.personRepository.DeletePersons(commonParam, new[] { personId });
    this.personRepository.SaveChanges();
}
```

And the `personRepository.DeletePersons` (but this one is faked by fakeiteasy...):

```
public void DeletePersons(CommonParam commonParam, IEnumerable<int> ids, bool hardRemove = false)
    {
           var persons = Entities.per_person.Where(e => ids.Contains(e.personId)
            && (e.accountId == null || e.accountId == commonParam.AccountId)).ToList();

        if (hardRemove)
        {
            Entities.per_person.RemoveRange(persons);
        }
        else
        {
            persons.ForEach(person =>
            {
                person.geloescht = true;
                person.mutationsBenutzer = commonParam.DbIdent;
                person.mutationsDatum = DateTime.Now;
            });
        }
    }
```

This is the reason why the test fails

> Test method DataService.Test.PersonServiceTest.DeletePerson_WhenCalled_ThenPersonIsDeleted threw exception: 
>   FakeItEasy.ExpectationException:
>
> Assertion failed for the following call:
>       RepositoryContract.IPersonRepository.DeletePersons(commonParam: Commons.CommonParam, ids: System.Int32[], hardRemove: False)
>     Expected to find it exactly once but found it #0 times among the calls:
>       1: RepositoryContract.IPersonRepository.RequestInfo = Faked Commons.Session.RequestInfo
>       2: RepositoryContract.IPersonRepository.DeletePersons(
>             commonParam: Commons.CommonParam,
>             ids: System.Int32[],
>             hardRemove: False)
>       3: RepositoryContract.IPersonRepository.SaveChanges()

Why does the test fail?

Is the `new[] { ... }` a problem?

Thanks in advance

Answer (score 5, accepted):

> Is the new[] { ... } a problem?

Yes,
`MustHaveHappened(Repeated.Exactly.Once)` will "pass" only when mocked method will be called with exact same parameters which you provide in the mock configuration.

```
A.CallTo(() => this.personRepository.DeletePersons(commonParam, new[] {personId }, false))
 .MustHaveHappened(Repeated.Exactly.Once);
```

For `commonParam` it works, because you passed same instance to the method under the test.

For `new[] {personId }` it doesn't work because array given in mock configuration and instance given in the method under the test are different instances of `int[]`.

You can use custom argument matching

```
A.CallTo(() => this.personRepository.DeletePersons(
                    commonParam, 
                    A<IEnumerable<int>>.That.Matches(ids => ids.Single() == personId), 
                    false))
 .MustHaveHappened(Repeated.Exactly.Once);
```

Or use more convenience and readable matching for your particular case as Thomas suggested. [More convenience matchers](https://fakeiteasy.readthedocs.io/en/stable/argument-constraints/#more-convenience-matchers)

Answer (score 5):

Fabio is correct, but you can make it a bit simpler:

```
A.CallTo(() => this.personRepository.DeletePersons(
                commonParam, 
                A<IEnumerable<int>>.That.IsSameSequenceAs(personId), 
                false))
 .MustHaveHappened(Repeated.Exactly.Once);
```

Answer (score 0):

> Is the new[] { ... } a problem?

Yes you are right. The `new[]` creates an array with the type you use between the {...} (It's assumed by the compiler). However your method declaration uses a `IEnumerable<int> ids`. So basically your test call is calling the wrong/unexisting method, due to signature mismatch.

Comment: Hmm are you sure? I mean the `new[] { ... }` is an `IEnumerable<T>` too not? I've tried to change the calls to `new List<int> { ... }` but it still doesn't work :-(

Comment: It is at run time, it is not in compile time. Cast any of those the others type.